# Mounting cifs share fails on boot but can be mounted by sudo, Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: mount, samba, 17.10, fstab, cifs

## Main issue

Since I updated to Ubuntu 17.10, I'm having trouble in mounting a `cifs` share via `fstab`. The following line is the one I use to connect.

```
//fs-cifs/home  /media/personal_mount   cifs    credentials=/home/<username>/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,rw,uid=1000,gid=1000,nounix,_netdev,vers=3.0,x-gfvs-show    0   0
```

The issue is that if I click on the Nautilus bookmark after booting the system, I get the error "Only root can mount" (or something similar).

Next I moved the share to `/mnt` instead of `/media` because somewhere (forgive me, but I totally forgot where) I read that that's a location where the system expects *removable* drives. I don't think that was the problem, also because after changing to the `/mnt` tree, the problem persists (i.e., the path `/mnt/personal_mount` is empty after reboot).

On the other hand, calling `sudo mount -a` works flawlessly and I can access the drive, its files, and make any modifications to them.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add parameter **user** to your string in `/etc/fstab` file: credentials=/home//.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,rw,uid=1000,gid=1000,nounix,_netdev,vers=3.0,x-gfvs-show,**user**

According to [Ubuntu's official documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab#Options) by default only root user is allowed to mount as it is mentioned in the error message.

Comment: Unfortunately, the `user` option did not change anything, the share is still not mounted at boot.

Comment: What about `auto` option?

Comment: Also no effect.